# Manipulate data frame inside a list

Tags: r, dataframe

this is presumably a simple question, but I have been unable to find an answer. 
I want to delete a column of a dataframe that is inside a list.

```
x1<- rnorm(100,0,1)
x2<- rnorm(100,0,1)
x3<- rnorm(100,0,1)
x4 <- rnorm(100,0,1)

df1 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
df2 <- data.frame(x4)

l1 <- list(df1,df2)

l1[1]

data.frame(l1[1])[,-1]

l1[1] <- data.frame(l1[1])[,-1]
```

Consider this example in which two dataframes, df1 and df2, are in list, l1. 
I want to delete column x1 out of df1. This is trivial to do if this is just a dataframe.
But once inside a list, I am not sure how to manipulate this dataframe.
When I try to overwrite it in the last statement, I am getting an error.

My actual problem has about 100 dataframes in a list and about 10% of them have an additional column that I need to delete. I can easily identify them with an lapply statement, but I don't know how to manipulate them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
l1[1] <- data.frame(l1[1])[,-1]
```

use

```
l1[[1]] <- data.frame(l1[1])[,-1]
```

Comment: The important distinction here being that `[[` accesses _elements_ of a list, while `[` accesses a _sub-list_.

Comment: Thank you very much joran and user2194122!